# Unable to pip install discord.py in python 3.6 on linux

Tags: python, linux, pip, discord, discord.py

I'm having trouble installing the [discord.py](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py) package into python 3.6. I've installed it before, but on my other PC which had python 3.4.

The command I am using is as follows:

```
python3.6 -m pip install -U discord.py
```

I am getting an error that looks like this, but I'm not sure what it is supposed to mean. Is the library not compatible with python 3.6, or am I doing something wrong? Forgive me if it's rather obvious; I'm new to python.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 183, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 142, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
    from pip.log import logger
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/log.py", line 9, in <module>
    import colorama, pkg_resources
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 646, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 616, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/setuptools-3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources.py", line 1479, in <module>
    register_loader_type(importlib_bootstrap.SourceFileLoader, DefaultProvider)
AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 20, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 183, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 142, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
    from pip.log import logger
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/log.py", line 9, in <module>
    import colorama, pkg_resources
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 646, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 616, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/setuptools-3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources.py", line 1479, in <module>
    register_loader_type(importlib_bootstrap.SourceFileLoader, DefaultProvider)
AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'
```

Comment: Can you try installing `python-apt` with `apt-get install python-apt`

Comment: I simply got a message stating that it was already up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

try doing these steps 1 by 1.

**1)** Create a directory anywhere called 'discord' or whatever you want

**2)** Download and extract this into the directory https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py

**3)** Hold down shift and right click when inside the directory with the discord.py extracted

**4)** Type: py setup.py
     or: py setup.py install

This should install it.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this method already however with no more  success than the above.

Comment: Try re installing python

Answer (score 0):

You can install the package manually using pip.

1) Download discord.py from [here](https://pypi.python.org/packages/97/3c/2a97b47fd8839f8863241857bbd6a3998d1de1662b788c8d9322e5a40901/discord.py-0.16.12.tar.gz)

2) Open command prompt and type in `pip install PathToThe.tar.gz/discord.py-0.16.12.tar.gz`

That should be all you need to do to manually install discord.py from pip. If you can do it w/o downloading the tar.gz or .whl file you should do it that way; I'm jumping to the conclusion that something went wrong during the file download.